# Add ltac expression as hint to autorewrite?

Tags: coq

I am trying to rewrite an environment using `autorewrite`. For simplicity we can assume it is a list (but in reality the type is more complex, has multiple cons constructors, and rewrite rules use equivalence rather than equality).

The normal form I want to get to is a concatenation of variables or singleton lists, i.e. `x1 :: x2 :: xs ++ y :: ys` to `[x1] ++ [x2] ++ xs ++ [y] ++ ys`. So far I had success rewriting other stuff by defining hints for `autorewrite`. However, the hint `forall x xs, xs :: x = xs ++ [x]` does not work, since `[x] = x : []` which then can be rewritten to `[x] ++ []` which gives an endless loop.

I don't have too much experience with writing custom Ltac expressions, but it seems like I would be able to define something like:

```
Ltac norm_cons :=
  match goal with
  | H: ?X : [] => idtac
  | H: ?X : ?XS => (* actual rewrite *)
  end.
```

This way we catch the `[]` in the first pattern and skip rewriting, and otherwise perform the rewrite. Maybe this needs a falltrough case, but this is not the point: how do I give (something like) this as a hint to `autorewrite`? I have tried to define the above as a separate tactic (where maybe I can define normalize as `(norm_cons; autorewrite with blablabla).`) but it then complains about none of the branches in the `match` matching to my goal. Does this do a recursive search? Or do I have to add this myself (i.e. matching `?XS ++ ?YS` and recursively rewriting the lhs and rhs?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you only want to rewrite lists with at least two elements.  Perhaps you could rewrite with

`forall x y xs, x :: y :: xs = [x] ++ y::xs`